# C++ eclipse. Abstract class won't compile

Tags: c++, abstract-class, header-files

I got a problem regarding Eclipse when creating abstract classes. I'm not very used to dealing with header files and such, my code basically looks as follows: (not displaying everything, just the basic class to give an idea of how it looks)

Equipment.h

```
namespace Equipments {

class Equipment{
public:
    virtual ~Equipment();
    virtual std::string get_category() const = 0;
protected:
    Equipment(std::string name);
private:
    const std::string name_;
};

class Weapon : public Equipment {
public:
    Weapon(std::string name, std::string something_else);

    virtual ~Weapon();

    std::string get_category() const override { return "Weapon"; };
private:
    const std::string something_else_;
};
} //end of namespace
```

Now, I got a problem with both the .h and .cpp file

in the .h file, under the weapon constructor, I'm used to writing (since I don't use header files):

```
Weapon(std::string name, std::string something_else)
    :    Equipment{name}, something_else_{something_else}
{}
```

Since I can't do this really (to my knowledge), how do I send parameters to my parent class? (in this case, letting eclipse know that I want my name parameter sent to Equipment parent class)

Should I do it in the .cpp file and if so, how?

And now the second problem.

In the .cpp file I create my equipment class like this:

```
namespace Equipments {

Equipment::Equipment(std::string name) {
    name_ = name;
}

Equipment::~Equipment() {
}

std::string Equipment::get_name()
{
    return name_;
}

//etc
```

But I can't seem to create my Weapon class. If I try:

```
Equipment::Weapon(std::string name, std::string something_else)
```

I just get member decleration not found, and if I try:

```
Weapon::Weapon(std::string name, std::string something_else)
```

I get no matching function for call to 'Equipments::Equipment::Equipment()'

I'm just stuck with not knowing how eclipse want me to write my code, I know it's a bit of a noob problem but I haven't been using either header files or c++ in eclipse for quite a long time. I'm really close to just pick my laptop and program in ubuntu and gedit instead so I don't have to deal with the header classes, however, then I won't learn anything either.

Comment: Eclipse is just an overblown text editor, you don't need to let it know anything, and it really isn't relevant here. Now, what does _can't do this really_ mean? Did you try and get an error? What error? Or did you just get the idea for some reason that it won't work?

Comment: Have you tried removing that specific error from error reporting (Preferences(or project properties) -> C++ -> Code Analysis)? Sometimes, Eclipse is just a little bit dumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I can't seem to create my Weapon class. If I try:

```
Equipment::Weapon(std::string name, std::string something_else)
```

> I just get member declaration not found,

Well, yes: your Weapon class is called `Weapon`, and it's constructor is called `Weapon::Weapon`. It *inherits* from `Equipment`, it isn't stored inside it.

> and if I try:

```
Weapon::Weapon(std::string name, std::string something_else)
```

> I get

```
no matching function for call to 'Equipments::Equipment::Equipment()'
```

That just means you left out the base class constructor (so it's trying to use the default constructor, which doesn't exist) - you don't show the whole code, but it ought to be

```
Weapon::Weapon(std::string name, std::string something_else)
  : Equipment(name)
  , something_else_(something_else)
{
}
```

Comment: Okay, it works now so thanks. I know it was a simple problem, but it's tricky if you're not 100% sure of how stuff works.

Comment: That's true, but trial and error isn't a winning strategy for learning this stuff _on its own_. I say this having spent an hour or more getting something tricky to compile today, but you need some reference material to get the foundation.